# Filter input to be validated and required in PHP

Tags: php, validation, input

I'm using PHP and `filter_input` function to filter `GET` variables and validate them:

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
```

But when the id parameter is not present in the URL, above statement will make `$id` NULL.

I want `$id` to be `false` when:

- it's not a valid integer or
- `$_GET["id"]` is not present.

This way, when I want to check if `$id` is valid in general, I compare it with `false` only. **Is there a way to validate an input variable and check for its presence with one single statement?** I think it's better to make `$id` `NULL` in above conditions, so there's no problem with Boolean inputs.

Currently I'm using above statement and the following `if` block:

```
if ($id !== false && $id !== NULL) {
   // statements to run when $id is valid and present
}
```

Comment: Is zero also an invalid ID?

Comment: @Scopey Yes, it could be. I want a general solution for this problem. Please consider other basic data types (string, bool, float) too.

Comment: `isset` returns false for `null` values. This doesn't cover the `$id === false` case though. You could try `is_int($id)` as that should cover all valid cases including zero.

Comment: @Scopey Great. I think this will work for other data types with similar functions too. +1

Comment: @deceze You even had a blog post about the usage of `isset`! All good - glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it around: `filter_input` will either return an `int` or one of two possible *falsey* values. To test whether it failed for any reason or you got an `int`, see whether you get an `int`:

```
if (is_int($id)) ...
```

The distinction between `false` and `null` further lets you discern what exactly went wrong if you so desire.